# Method and constructor implementation

Tags: java, methods, constructor

My code does not currently compile, I know that it is due to a lack of a return for my constructor- but if I could please get some help (as I have a version that I have already tried to fix), it would greatly be appreciated.

I have 2 files, one that has a constructor, and one that accesses that constructor. I should also note, that all of the help I found online said that I have to use an if else statement, but that leads to more errors.

My code for the main file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;//importing scanner 

public class QuestionTwo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberofDays;//these two lines define variables
    int sharePoints;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);//activating scanner
System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");//asking question

numberofDays = keyboard.nextInt();//obtaining input by defining a variable as a keyboard input

System.out.print("Share points on the first day: ");//asking another question
sharePoints = keyboard.nextInt();//obtaining input by defining a variable as a keyboard input
while (numberofDays < 10 || numberofDays > 20)
{
    System.out.println("The number of days doesn’t meet the required criteria, enter it again");
    System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");
    numberofDays = keyboard.nextInt();
}

SharePattern share = new SharePattern(numberofDays, sharePoints);
SharePattern.outPutTablePrinter(numberofDays, sharePoints);
//above two lines print day and share points, as well as the first line 
of text (as it does not change)


}

}
```

Here is the code for the constructor (the one with the return error):

```
public class SharePattern {
   private static int days;
   private static int share;

public SharePattern(int numberofDays, int sharePoints)//constructor
{
 numberofDays=days;
 sharePoints=share;

}
public static int outPutTablePrinter(int numberofDays,int sharePoints){

    for (int i = 2; i <= days; i++) {
        if (days % 2 == 0)
            if (i <= days / 2) {
                share = share + 50;
            } else {
                share = share - 25;

            } else {
            if (i <= days / 2 + 1) {
                share = share + 50;
            } else {
                share = share - 25;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The share points on the final day would be: "+share);
}
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I've been working on this problem all day and finally got finished when I came upon this problem.

Comment: You set the fields  backwards... I highly doubt you want static fields either. And your method must return something

Comment: remove the extra curly brace at the end and give your method a return value.

Comment: your inverse numberofDays=days; sharePoints=share; should be days=numberofDays; share=sharePoints; in your constructor SharePattern

Comment: @Aominè what would the return value be, I'm sorry for my incompetency

Comment: What @Aominè whant said is your method outPutTablePrinter have a return value but return nothing change it to void

Comment: Constructors don't return values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have an `else {} else`, which isn't valid

Not really clear which you're trying to accomplish..

### Option 1

Remove the constructor and the static fields. You never use `share` variable.

Make your `outPutTablePrinter` method use the parameters you passed to it. And that method doesn't return anything. It's printing a value. Make it `public static void`

### Option 2

If you want to keep the constructor, you need to flip the order of those equal statements and remove the `static` keyword.

Still make the method void

```
public class SharePattern {
    private int days;
    private int share;

    public SharePattern(int numberofDays, int sharePoints){
        days = numberofDays;
        share = sharePoints;
    }

    public void outPutTablePrinter() {
```

And in the main method, you must use `share.outPutTablePrinter()`

Answer (score 0):

It was actually extremely simple (sorry for my incompetence once again):

I should have put

```
return (sharePoints);
```

where i previously had nothing

Comment: The parentheses are not needed, and did you mean to return share?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i suggest you if i understand correctly your code

**SharePattern.class**

```
private static int days;
private static int share;

public SharePattern(int numberofDays, int sharePoints)//constructor
{
    days=numberofDays;
    share=sharePoints;

}
public static void outPutTablePrinter(){

    for (int i = 2; i <= days; i++) {
        if (days % 2 == 0)
            if (i <= days / 2) {
                share = share + 50;
            } else {
                share = share - 25;
            }
        else
            if (i <= days / 2 + 1) {
                share = share + 50;
            } else {
                share = share - 25;
            }
    }
    System.out.println("The share points on the final day would be: "+share);
}
```